# Firebase analytics data collection: log messages

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-analytics

Firebase analytics data collection is permanently deactivated in my app:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated"
   android:value="true" />
```

But when the app starts, there is this log:

```
I/FA-Ads: App measurement deactivated via the manifest
I/FA-Ads: App measurement initialized, version: 26016
```

Is the second log message wrong?
(if app measurement is deactivated, maybe it shouldn't be initialized).

Play-services-version is 19.1.0 (12451000).

Answer (score 0):

Firebase analytics will activate on start anyway to gather some data which might be crucial when you enable Firebase later on, like information where the user came from.

It's normal to see Firebase activity, but you should also see `Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled` in logs. Of course no data will be actually sent to the server until you enable Firebase Analytics in code.